# Basic inequalities proof : if a > b - c implies a > c ?

Tags: inequality

I have $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$ (strictly positive real numbers) and $ a > b - c$. Does it imply that : $a > c $ ? if yes hints to the proof may be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try some examples?

Comment: Did you try anything?  Maybe pick some particular values?

Comment: $2 > 10 - 9$, but ...

Comment: I think you should try some examples before writting the question.

Comment: where does you guess come from? It is of course not true in general

Comment: No. Let $a=5,b=7,c=6$. Then $5>7-6=1$, but $5\not > 6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b$ and $c$ are both small, your idea works fine. E.g. $5>4-1; 5>1$
However, if they are both large (relative to $a$) and close together, the theory falls apart. For example: $5>(10,005-10,001)$, but clearly $5\not>10,001$. I'm sure there are infinitely many such counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a short answer, which could very well just be a comment, but I would like for you to remember this in the future:

> Substitute $b = a + c - 1$. Then, $a > a + c - 1 - c$ if and only if $a > a - 1$ or $1 > 0$, which is true. So, $b \leqslant a + c - 1$.

But, since all of them are positive, then if $a > b - c$, one has that $a > b$. I think this is what you meant, and not $a > c$.

Comment: Shall I put this as a comment? I think so...

Comment: @AlexSilva It has been edited. Thank you for letting me know. It was like saying if $x > y$ then $1/x > 1/y$, but as we all know, the larger the denominator...

Comment: Why $ b = a+c-1$?

Comment: @AlexSilva because $a,b,c$ are **strictly positive**. From the substitution, I get that $b\leqslant a + c - 1$.

Comment: I know. It does not answer my question. $a=4$, $b = 5$ and $c = 3$ are strictly positives and  $b\neq a+c-1$

Comment: @AlexSilva yes but $b \leqslant a + c - 1$ or more precisely, $b < a + c - 1$. I see your point though. It was perhaps a weird way to obtain the inequality